# Creating charts using array values in Php/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have output in arrays as below, I'm trying to read space-separated values and use them in charts. I'm trying to do this using PHP, HTML. But I'm unable to get to the exact values after space. What would be the easiest way to form a chart like bar chart or horizontal bar chart using below?

```
    `[53] => X Y Z W M
    [54] => ------------------------------ --------- ------ ---------- ------- 
    [55] => A 89.7 59.8 152 N/A 
    [56] => B 5.0 71.8 1 NO 
    [57] => C 348.0 63.9 4 NO 
    [58] => D 372.0 78.3 4 NO `
```

Comment: please give us a real array so we can copy easily

Comment: What @yoss said, and also, stack overflow isn't meant to be a place where we always write you an answer. We want to help you become a better developer by giving you tips  and resources to accomplish what you're trying to do. We can help you in any matter with existing code, however bad it is, so please add an example with code that you've tried to use to read the array and we can help you explain why the code isn't working. That'll also make us understand what level you're on so we can use simple or advanced explainations :)

Comment: @JonathanNielsen Agree. I dont have any code on reading array as yet, I'm just trying to understand how do get the right  details that I really need in this case, or if there is better of way doing it ?

Comment: @yoss we store results in URL, i fetched details using cURL and above is the array i'm trying to work with. I'm using php and html for this. I'm trying to find a way for it to print the value that I need like we do using awk in unix. I'm trying to create horizontalbar chart using above array table name and %used

Comment: do you get the array in your Q?  as text ? or as an array if yes in what language?

Comment: as an array in PHP

Comment: It sounds pretty basic, you should head over to w3schools or php.net for some simple PHP array examples and documentation. See for example https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp.
Here you are shown how to get values from an array.

Comment: I still dont get it, how do get to values that I need for chart, e.g. how do I grep W value for  B from given arrays